# ROLE symfony FOS

Tags: php, symfony, hierarchy, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to set role to a specific user.

I do this roles:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ENTRAINEUR:  ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:  
        - ROLE_USER
        - ROLE_ENTRAINEUR
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: 
        - ROLE_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ENTRAINEUR
        - ROLE_USER
```

Then I do:

```
    - { path: ^/affichePresences, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I try too, to promote user, but user pass from user directly to admin and not to ENTRAINEUR.

Somebody know why?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md#4-promote-a-user), you should specify desired role:

```
php app/console fos:user:promote username ROLE_ENTRAINEUR
```